# SQL Server, Insert into table from select query?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I would fill a table from a query in a stored procedure,

This works:

```
SELECT * 
INTO #tmpTable 
FROM MyTable
```

This works:

```
SELECT TOP (1) * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE Land = @Land
```

but how do I fill `#tmpTable` with

```
SELECT TOP (1) * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE Land = @Land
```

Comment: `SELECT TOP (1) * INTO #tmpTable FROM MyTable WHERE Land = @Land`? This question might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure?rq=1

Comment: @MeerArtefakt, what exactly are you looking for? Can you describe your problem statement clearly?

Comment: @Manoj: I would see the #tmpTable from my stored procedure as a return value. later i would work with the table from my c# code

Comment: @jpw: it works fine!

but why I can't see the table after executing the the stored procedure?

Do I need "SELECT * from #tmpTable" after "SELECT TOP (1) * INTO #tmpTable FROM MyTable WHERE Land = @Land" ?

Comment: You want to get records stored in your #temp table from the SP in the end, right? In this case you can do a "SELECT * from #tempTable" in the end of the SP, which will return all records after the SP execution completes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the #temp Table's scope is limited to its session (SPID), i.e. the Stored Procedure itself. After the SP execution completes the #temp table is Dropped.

Also while the SP is being executed you cannot see the #temp Table from other sessions (SPID)

Comment: perhaps suggest returning the temp table into a table variable output parameter using `select * from #temp` as a way to get at the data from the calling code or if required use a ##globalTempTable.

Answer (score 1):

USE Global temp table like ##temp even it can be accessible after execution of sp also